# "camping" vs. "camped" under a bridge

Tags: past-participles

If you were to describe a group of poor illegal immigrants who live in tents under a bridge, would you say that they are "camping" under a bridge, or that they are "camped" under a bridge?

If I write "Homeless man camping under a bridge" (e.g. in a photo caption) might it perhaps sound like he is camping there for fun? Does "camping" sound like it's a leisure activity, and "camped" (as a past participle) like it's a makeshift form of accommodation for the homeless?

Answer (score 4):

The assumption in your second paragraph sounds correct to me. "Camping" is a leisure activity, while "being camped" is fun-neutral and can apply to the homeless, soldiers, etc.